# Disconnect and Connect hook for WalletConnectButton

Tags: web3.js, solana-wallet-adapter, react

i am using the WalletConnectButton from @solana/wallet-adapter-react-ui in my React app. I want to execute additional logic when the user connects and disconnects their wallet. Is there a way to do that? thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're using React the easiest way to do this would be with a `useEffect` hook.

```
import { useWallet } from '@solana/wallet-adapter-react';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

export default function MyComponent() {
  const { publicKey } = useWallet()
  const [hasConnected, setHasConnected] = useState(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    if(publicKey) {
      setHasConnected(true)
      // do stuff after connect
    } else {
      if(hasConnected) {
        // do stuff after disconnect
      }
    }
  }, [publicKey])

  return <div>whatever</div>
}
```

Since `publicKey` is in the dependency array, that effect will re-run with the newest value of `publicKey` available every time it changes.

Comment: the problem with this is "// do stuff after disconnect" line gets called when you refresh the page

Comment: I edited the answer to show how to avoid this. You can add a `hasConnected` state, default it to false, set it to true in the `if(publicKey)` branch, and then condition the disconnect logic on that being true.